# Farmer and owner Bayesian game

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory

A farmer has talent $\theta$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. His payoff from farming his land is $\theta.$ Before setting up his farm, he chooses some $w\geq0$, which a plant owner can either accept or reject. If the owner rejects, then the farmer farms on his own, and the owner gets 0. If the owner accepts, then the farmer's payoff is $w$, while the owner's is $\frac{3}{2}\theta-w$.

I have found the following BNE: farmer offers some $w\geq\theta$ and the owner rejects all offers. Do others arrive at this as well? Thank you.

Comment: Does the farmer offer $w$ before or after she knows what $\theta$ is?

Comment: @WalrasianAuctioneer After she knows what $\theta$ is.

Comment: What is the owner's payoff if they reject?

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry 0.

Comment: Another BNE (and infact a PBE) is one where a type $\theta$ farmer offers $w = \frac{3}{2}\theta$ and the owner always accepts.

Comment: @WalrasianAuctioneer How is this derived?

Comment: What exactly are you asking in this question? Are you asking us to verify your equilibrium or asking for other equilibria in this game?

Comment: @WalrasianAuctioneer To verify my own. Suggestion of other equilibria is welcome as well.

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question and show us what you have tried (how you derived such equilibrium and so on) and we can go from there.